# Can I change format of text between '' in Libre Office?

Tags: libreoffice, format, writing

I have a document in LibreOffice where I use `‘’` to mark inner thoughts. Once I finish with edits, I turn this text along with `‘’` into italic. However, I know only about manual way, and I'm wondering if there is a way to automatize it?

I tried to play with it using `\` or `*` and looking for a format in Search&Replace Function, but I had no luck.

Here is an example:

```
Kairo’s mouth twitched. ‘What a surprise. This may be for once easy.’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a regular expression. Search for `‘(.+)’` and set the format of the replace text to italics:

[image]

If you want to keep the quotes, replace with `$0`, if you want the quotes removed, replace with `$1`

NOTE: I recommend you do a controlled search rather than to replace all as you may find quotes that don't indicate dialog (ex.: `‘what’s the matter?’`)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked like a charm :-D